# How can I modify a static property?

Tags: c#

I am tring to motify a static property, I don't know where I am getting wrong. Here is the code.

```
        public static string Id
    {
        get { return Id; }
        set
        {
            if (Id.Length < Idlen)
            {
                var zero = new string('0', Idlen - Id.Length);
                Id = zero + Id;
                Id = value;
            }
            else
            {
                Id = Id.Substring(Id.Length - Idlen);
                Id = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public static int Idlen { get; set; }
```

Comment: Currently your `Id` property is recursive. It looks like you should be declaring a private field that your `Id` property manipulates.

Comment: `return Id` will surely run the properties getter again, which yields to en endless recursion. You probably want a private backing-field, e.g. `_id` or whatever.

Comment: @HimBromBeere which would cause a.... StackOverflow exception ;-)

Comment: Properties are of two diferent type. a) Bodyless ones `public static int MyProperty {get; set;}` or b) With code in their `get` and `set`. When they have body/code, there should exist a `private static string _Id;` variable that the getter and setter should use.

Answer (score 1):

So here is an example of what I *think* you are trying to achieve. (Although ReSharper is telling me not to use these field names...)

```
private static string _Id;

public static string Id
{
    get => _Id;
    set // You want to use value here (new value), not Id (old value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            // Consider what you want to do if user calls Id = null
            _Id = new string('0', Idlen);
        }
        else if (value.Length < Idlen)
        {
            var zero = new string('0', Idlen - value.Length);
            _Id = zero + value;
        }
        else
        {
            _Id = value.Substring(value.Length - Idlen);
        }
    }
}
public static int Idlen { get; set; }
```